# Modified htaccess with recommendations of SEO software. Can't get everything to work at the same time

Tags: .htaccess, custom-error-pages

I added some lines to my htaccess to fix a few SEO errors. These new lines caused other errors. Now I can't get everything to work properly at the same time.

I need two things. First, when a page is not found, I need the website to indicate a 404 error at 404-error.php (not index.php). Secondly, When I go to blog/ or blog/index.php the page does not work unless I remove other portions of the code. When I put that code back in the site won't show a 404 error when trying to access a page that doesn't exist. As of right now, if a page isn't found it forwards to blog/index.php

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect index.php to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: _"When I put that code back in the site won't show a 404 error when trying to access a page that doesn't exist. As of right now, if a page isn't found it forwards to blog/index.php"_ - of course, that's how the front controller pattern _works_. Every request that does not match onto an existing file or folder, gets rewritten to your script - so that your script can then go check the database, whether it has any content to show for the requested URL. And if it doesn't - then it is your script's responsibility, to respond with a 404 status code.

Comment: The `ErrorDocument 404` simply has no effect any more in this kind of setup, _because_ all requests for non-existing files & folders are rewritten to your script.

Comment: is `index.php` something you programmed yourself?  Can you modify it to show 404 errors when appropriate?